# React conditionally opening different divs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to conditionally open divs two and three, take a look at following snippet. showThird works correct however, showSecond has no effect? Basically on showSecond div-one shrinks to 50% width and div-two appears in rest 50%. Similar with div-third.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showSecond: false,
            showThird: false
        }

        this.showDivTwo = this.showDivTwo.bind(this)
        this.showDivThree = this.showDivThree.bind(this)
    }
  
  showDivTwo() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({showThird: false, showSecond: !prevState.showSecond}))
        console.log(this.state)

    }
    showDivThree() {

        this.setState(prevState => ({ showSecond: false, showThird: !prevState.showThird}))
        console.log(this.state)
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
       <div className={'wrapper' + (this.state.showSecond ? ' show' : '', this.state.showThird ? ' show' : '')}>

                <div className="one">one
                    {/* Show second */}
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivTwo}>{this.state.showSecond ? 'hideSecond' : 'showSecond'}</button>
                    </div>

                    {/* Show third */}
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="three">three
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="two">two
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivTwo}>{this.state.showSecond ? 'hideSecond' : 'showSecond'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.one, .two, .three {
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #787567;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: border 0.2s, padding 0.2s, width 0.2s;
  min-height: 50vh;

}

.one {
  width: 100%;
}
.two {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
}

.three {
  border-width: 2px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
}

.show .one, .show .two, .show .three {
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

1- use this condition:

```
className={'wrapper' + (this.state.showSecond || this.state.showThird ? ' show' : '')}
```

2- Use one more class `hide`, and put the check on `className`, apply that `class` if you want to hide the `div` otherwise apply class `two or three`.

Check the working code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showSecond: false,
            showThird: false
        }

        this.showDivTwo = this.showDivTwo.bind(this)
        this.showDivThree = this.showDivThree.bind(this)
    }
  
  showDivTwo() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({showThird: false, showSecond: !prevState.showSecond}))
        console.log(this.state)

    }
    showDivThree() {

        this.setState(prevState => ({ showSecond: false, showThird: !prevState.showThird}))
        console.log(this.state)
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
       <div className={'wrapper' + (this.state.showSecond || this.state.showThird ? ' show' : '')}>

                <div className="one">
                    one
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivTwo}>{this.state.showSecond ? 'hideSecond' : 'showSecond'}</button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div className={this.state.showThird?"three":'hide'}>
                   three
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivThree}>{this.state.showThird ? 'hideThird' : 'showThird'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={this.state.showSecond ? "two" : 'hide'}>two
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.showDivTwo}>{this.state.showSecond ? 'hideSecond' : 'showSecond'}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hide, .one, .two, .three {
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #787567;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: border 0.2s, padding 0.2s, width 0.2s;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.one {
   width: 100%;
 }

.hide {
   border-width: 2px 0;
   padding: 20px 0;
   width: 0;
}

.show .one, .show .two, .show .three {
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that's awesome! Thanks a lot! It's just that while closing if you see it goes abruptly  with flashing white screen unlike in my question. Could you perhaps improve that as well?

Comment: Conditional showing somehow breaks the animation while closing :(

Comment: Yes definitely! Thanks a lot!